# Method create (int, int) in the type TopScoreDocCollector is not capable for the arguments (int, boolean)

Tags: java, eclipse, lucene

currently i am working with Apache Lucene and i get error in this section:

```
TopScoreDocCollector collector = TopScoreDocCollector.create(hitsPerPage, true);
```

It says:

> "The method **create** (int, int) in the type TopScoreDocCollector is not capable for the arguments (int, boolean)"

And this is my full code, i got this from [HelloLucene.java](https://github.com/macluq/HelloLucene/blob/master/src/main/java/HelloLucene/HelloLucene.java) with a little modification.

I work with Eclipse and Apache Lucene 8.4.0. I have no idea because im too confused. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simply means exactly what it says. 
In Apache Lucene 8.4.0 there is not a create-Method which takes (int,boolean) as input.
Check the API for your version:
http://lucene.apache.org/core/8_4_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/TopScoreDocCollector.html

Comment: it solved! i just need change the threshold to 0. thank you!